# Change Variable Names Across Multiple Python Files

Tags: python, directory

I am going through a directory of python scripts and changing a variable in each script. This is taxing as there are hundreds of python scripts in the directory I am sorting through. Is there a way to write a python script that goes through each file and changes the variable to what I want?

the variable calls a file path as a string, i.e.

```
filepath = '/directory/subdirectory/'
```

I would like to change it for each script accordingly:

```
filepath = '/directory/othersubdirectory/'
```

the variable is called the same thing in each script

Comment: Can you demonstrate *any* effort at solving this yourself?

Comment: Good opportunity to define that path on a constant rather than having it hard-coded into hundreds of files. If you have to change it again in the future, only one place to edit and it's done!

Comment: @JordanBrière not sure what you mean by "on a constant", can you explain that?

Comment: Have a single module that defines `SOME_PATH = '/directory/othersubdirectory/'`, and import that constant into all the others so that you don't have to edit all files but only that single constant if you ever need to change it again.

Comment: @JordanBrière thanks, I'll keep that in mind for future reference!

Comment: @ScottHunter Sorry to say I have no idea how to alter python files using another python script, so I don't know where to start.

Answer (score 0):

This depends on your variable name. If it is something unique, where it won't appear anywhere but if it's the variable name, then you can use a for loop to go through the files, and use `.replace()` to replace the variable with the new variable name, but if you have used a bad variable name, something like `x`, then the letter x might show up in your code in places other than your variable, in which case you cannot use the `.replace()` method as it will replace everything, not just your variable.

By a for loop, I mean making a list of your subdirectories, connecting it to the base directory, opening it, and then using the `replace` function.

Note: I can't say this for sure since I don't have enough information about how your directories are structured and how many you need to change, but this method could be time consuming.

Comment: This might work, although I think you're confusing what I'm trying to do here; I want to change the value assigned to the variable in each file, not what the variable is called. Can I still do what you are suggesting with that in mind?